# Contributors Post Edits Set to Pending

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

The default behaviour of Wordpress means that contributors can't publish new posts. They are saved as drafts and await approval. However when a contributor edits an existing post they can publish their changes without the need for approval.

I would like to stop all contributor post edits from being published and instead set them to 'pending'.

I have tried the following with no success (functions.php)

```
$role = get_role('contributor');

if ( ! empty($role))
{
    $role->remove_cap('publish_post');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities a Contributor should not have the ability to edit a published post.

Possibly you'll need to remove the capability like so:

```
$role = get_role( 'contributor' );
$role->remove_cap( 'edit_published_posts' );
```

Comment: By default a contributor can edit their own posts once they have been published by another user. The above does not achieve what I'm looking for.

Comment: To be more specific 'edit_published_posts' is assigned to contributors by default. Removing this will not allow contributors to edit their own posts completely. I want them to edit their own posts but the status must them be set to 'pending'.

Comment: I don't believe that can be easily achieved with editing the roles

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best way to achieve this but by using add_filter I can modify the post status once the post is submitted.

In functions.php

```
if (current_user_can('contributor'))
{
    //function to set pending status
    function dont_publish( $data , $postarr ) {  
      if ( in_category('mycategory') ) {
        $data['post_status'] = 'pending';   
      }
      return $data;
    }
    //apply the pending status
    add_filter('wp_insert_post_data' , 'dont_publish' , '99', 2); 
}
```

This also allows you to also only apply the filter on a set category as well as the contributor role.